# connect a github repository to power BI

Tags: github

i have been trying to  clone my Github repository to Power Bi so i can commit all my power BI files to Github.

Assistance would be very appreciated

I tried downloading the GitHub on Power Bi service but i still get stuck

Answer (score 0):

This [thread mentions](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Integrating-GIT-with-PowerBI/td-p/2086371):

> If you just want to integrate Git with PowerBI, the most straightforward way is to use [GitHub template app](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/getapps/services/pbi-contentpacks.pbiapps-github).
>
> - [`service-connect-to-github`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-connect-to-github)
> - [`service-tutorial-connect-to-github`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-tutorial-connect-to-github)
>
> You can also consider third-party platforms, but they are usually not free of charge:
>
> - [Connecting GitHub to Power BI using Hevo](https://hevodata.com/learn/github-to-power-bi/)
> - https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/github/powerbi/

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I just came across Tugger (https://tuggerapp.com/) for connecting to GitHub. They have a few connectors, but the GitHub might be their most recent.

It gives an OData link and password credentials, a 30 day free trial, and perhpas the best of all, a report template to get started.

Hopefully this might help out someone doing what I've been doing, namely trying to find a solution and not have to code it myself!